# Selective JSON Serialization using ASMX Web Service

Tags: asp.net, json, serialization, asmx

I have a webservice that I use to get JSON formatted custom classes, for example:

```
    public class custom
    {
        private int _myPrivateProperty;

        public int ToBeAccessedOnlyInCode
        {
            get
            {
                return _myPrivateProperty;
            }
            set 
            {
                _myPrivateProperty = value; 
            }
        }

       public int ToBeSerialized
       {
            get
            {
                return _myPrivateProperty * 1000;
            }
       }
   }
```

The above example is for illustration purposes.

The problem is that I don't want to return the original object format in the JSON response, but I need the original format in my code.

I have tried [DataContract]/[DataMemeber] attributes in the class, leaving out the ToBeOnlyAccessedInCode property, I have tried using the [NonSerialized] attribute above my private object container.  All to no avail.

IS there a way in which I can prevent a field from being serialized to JSON when using the built in ASMX scriptserializer?  I've spent a good few hours looking and could do with the help!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

found it:

[System.Web.Script.Serialization.ScriptIgnore]